# Hide Show Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, hide, show

I need some help with Jquery.

I have a div which contains multiple unique images and id's.
When I click on the image with the id=image1 , I want to show the div imageinfo with the  image1image class.

I dont want to show the image2image and image3image classes when I have clicked image1.

```
<style>
body{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}

.imagecontainer img{
    width:250px; 
    float:left;
}

.imageinfo{
    background:white;
    opacity:0.9;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    display:none;
}

#close{
    position:absolute;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    top:30px;
    right:30px;
}
</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // hide information about image when button close is clicked
    $(".close").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().hide();
    });


    /* here I need the code to show the imageinfo and the image[number]image class
    depending on which image was clicked.
    */
});
</script>

<!-- container -->
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="image1.png" id="image1">
    <img src="image2.png" id="image2">
    <img src="image3.png" id="image3">
</div>

<!-- image info -->
<div class="imageinfo">
    <div class="image1image"><img src="image1.png"></div>
    <div class="image2image"><img src="image2.png"></div>
    <div class="image3image"><img src="image3.png"></div>
    <div id="close">CLOSE</div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: you need to show the html and what have you tried with jquery?

Comment: I only tried it per image.. so the jquery were:

$("#image1").click(function(){
$("#imageinfo").show();
$(".image1image").show();}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to know id of clicked image. Then set up element which to show it.

```
$('.imagecontainer img').click(function() {
        // all hide
        $('.imageinfo div').hide();

        // get id of clicked img
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);

        // show info img
        $('.imageinfo .'+id).show();
    });
```

look at my solution

http://jsfiddle.net/e66uo3ra/

Comment: iam glad. Sometimes you can not use ID for any reason. I prefere use html5 data attribut for this. More info http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
$('img[id^="image"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div[class^="' + id + '"]').show();
});
```

This will bind a click event to every matching `img` element, and in that event will get the `id` of the element which was clicked and use that `id` to select a `div` to show.

You might even do this with a single click handler instead of one for each element.  Something like this:

```
$('div.imagecontainer').on('click', 'img[id^="image"]', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div[class^="' + id + '"]').show();
});
```

That would attach only a single click handler to the containing `div` and use event delegation to handle the click events.